# Is having square bracket in table name supported in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I wish to have a table name with

```
hello [world]
```

So, I thought using the following syntax would work

```
create table [hello [world]]] (key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
```

I get

```
Error: unrecognized token: "]"
```

I was wondering, is having square bracket supported in SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try quoting the table name:

```
$ sqlite3 :memory:
sqlite> create table "Foo [bar]" (a int);
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE "Foo [bar]" (a int);
sqlite> insert into "Foo [bar]" values(1);
sqlite> select * from "Foo [bar]";
1
sqlite> _
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if the table name contains double quotes?

Comment: Double double quotes quote themselves: `create table "In ""double"" quotes" (a int);` then `.tables` will show `In "double" quotes` among tables. Though possible, I have hard time imagining when such a name is _desirable_.

Comment: This is because I was considering to use "multiple portfolio name" as table name. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692723/database-design-in-android-sqlite-multiple-tables-or-2-tables-for-multiple-por However, it might appear to be bad design. So, I'm currently experimenting with it...

Answer (score 2):

There are [multiple methods for quoting identifiers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

When using square brackets, it is not possible to have these characters in the identifier.

When using double quotes, you can escape them in the name by doubling them:

```
CREATE TABLE "hello ""world"""(key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
```